# Migrate systemusers to CRM with Scribe

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, scribe-workbench

Im trying to migrate the systemuser from CRM OnPremise to CRMOnline using Scribe.

I mapped in my dts all the required fields but the next error happen all the time:

> This is not a valid Microsoft Online Services ID for this organization.

The only guid mapped is the businesunit so I dont see the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not work. In CRM Onine used other approach. You will have to create users manually.

Comment: That{s what I was affraid of :/
I think I will have to create the users using powershell because I try with the office.portal and 5 days passed before the users appears on CRM